# HID communication between Arduino Uno and computer

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, hid

I used some firmware I found online to turn the UNO into an emulated HID device. The Arduino is no longer connected to a Serial COM port so I can't send serial data from my computer to the device. Is there a way that the Arduino can receive data from the computer in order to drive a function while in the HID emulated state?

Comment: yes, if the HID has an input channel

Comment: the 'some firmware' would have to support it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a second USB on the PC and use Hardware Serial to transmit commands. (Either via a second Arduino or a FTDI adapter)
 But be aware that at least the [firmware I use](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) and the controller programs are very sensitive to being disturbed in the loop. So you should have a good understanding of timers, interupts and non blocking code.

Comment: doesn't NicoHood support Serial and HID together?